# Listening for multiple keypress events at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Alright, so I'm developing a simple clone of [Agar](http://agar.io) but with only 2 players. I've gotten most of the basic functionality down except I can't figure out how to handle keypress events from both players at the same time. (only one can move at a time) Here's my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/khanfused/oso9uepf/). Relevant snippet:

```
if (keysArr.toString() === "37,87") {
    player.dir = "left";
    player2.dir = "up";
    keys = [];
} 

if (keysArr.toString() === "38,87") {
    player.dir = "up";
    player2.dir = "up";
}

if (keysArr.toString() === "39,87") {
    player.dir = "right";
    player2.dir = "up";
}

if (keysArr.toString() === "40,87") {
    player.dir = "down";
    player2.dir = "up";
} 

if (keysArr.toString() === "37,65") {
    player.dir = "left";
    player2.dir = "left";
} 

if (keysArr.toString() === "38,65") {
    player.dir = "up";
    player2.dir = "left";
} 

if (keysArr.toString() === "39,65") {
    player.dir = "right";
    player2.dir = "left";
} 

if (keysArr.toString() === "40,65") {
    player.dir = "down";
    player2.dir = "left";
} 

if (keysArr.toString() === "37,83") {
    player.dir = "left";
    player2.dir = "down";
} 

if (keysArr.toString() === "38,83") {
    player.dir = "up";
    player2.dir = "down";
} 

if (keysArr.toString() === "39,83") {
    player.dir = "right";
    player2.dir = "down";
} 

if (keysArr.toString() === "40,83") {
    player.dir = "down";
    player2.dir = "down";
} 

if (keysArr.toString() === "37,68") {
    player.dir = "left";
    player2.dir = "right";
} 

if (keysArr.toString() === "38,68") {
    player.dir = "up";
    player2.dir = "right";
} 

if (keysArr.toString() === "39,68") {
    player.dir = "right";
    player2.dir = "right";
} 

if (keysArr.toString() === "40,68") {
    player.dir = "down";
    player2.dir = "right";
} 

if (keysArr.toString() === "37") {
    player.dir = "left";
} 

if (keysArr.toString() === "38") {
    player.dir = "up";
} 

if (keysArr.toString() === "39") {
    player.dir = "right";
} 

if (keysArr.toString() === "40") {
    player.dir = "down";
}
```

I couldn't figure out another way, so I just used a bunch of if's.

So, this code lets two players move at the same time, but after the initial one, they can't turn again. How would I make it so both can move at the same time and turn afterwards as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second key that is pressed while the first one is held down is being detected, as the other player will move.

**You must change all the ELSEIF's to simply IFs.** Tying the player 2 elseif to a player 1 if means that if player 1 presses a key it will never get to player 2's elseif condition. This will solve your main problem.

The document.onkeydown and document.onkeyup listeners do not need to be initialized every repetition, only once.

I modified your jsFiddle to reflect these changes. I then got carried away and also placed the code in document.onkeyup to cause players to stop moving, as it was bothering me. Enjoy! https://jsfiddle.net/wtqk7Lu2/1/

```
if (player2.dir === keys.w) {
    player2.y -= player2.speed.y;
}
if (player.dir === keys.up) {
    player.y -= player.speed.y;
}
if (player2.dir === keys.a) {
    player2X -= player2.speed.x;
}
if (player.dir === keys.left) {
    player1X -= player.speed.x;
}
if (player2.dir === keys.s) {
    player2.y += player2.speed.y;
}
if (player.dir === keys.down) {
    player.y += player.speed.y;
}
if (player2.dir === keys.d) {
    player2X += player2.speed.x;
}
if (player.dir === keys.right) {
    player1X += player.speed.x;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. However, I did re-edit it to make it keep moving as that's what makes Agar challenging; you can't stop.